# out put to a file all on one line powershell

Tags: powershell

Code -

```
Write-Output "No. Excluded files:" $Global:exclusioncount | Out-File DryRun.txt -append
```

However the variable gets outputted on a different line. Is there anyway to make it output on the same line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways you could solve this:

```psh
Write-Output ("No. Excluded files:{0}" -f $Global:exclusioncount) | Out-File DryRun.txt -append

Write-Output "No. Excluded files:$($Global:exclusioncount)" | Out-File DryRun.txt -append

Write-Output ("No. Excluded files:" + $Global:exclusioncount) | Out-File DryRun.txt -append
```